# ERROR 1138: Invalid use of NULL value SQL Statement: ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN LONGTEXT NOT NULL

Tags: mysql

Trying to change the NULL to a NOT NULL in MySQL editor and this error pops up.
Following is the log

```
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `anylogic`.`anydata` 
CHANGE COLUMN `Start_Production` `Start_Production` LONGTEXT NOT NULL ;

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1138: Invalid use of NULL value
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `anylogic`.`anydata` 
CHANGE COLUMN `Start_Production` `Start_Production` LONGTEXT NOT NULL
```

Comment: There is no question actually..

Comment: How can I resolve this error?

Comment: @mo6105 - have a look at my first comment. There is the same question with answer.

Comment: I tried that solution but, I don't know the identifier for type LONGTEXT to set